# Banner between Product Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, product-list

i found this solution for display a banner between the products grid view.
The code show the banner every 4th product but i will show the banner only once after the 4th element.

My code which is based after the  inside the /catalog/product/list.phtml:

```
<?php if($i % 4 == 0){ ?>
   <li class="advert-banner-first">
      <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('catalogfirstbannermarkthalle')->toHtml(); ?>
   </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks, for help.

Here is the complete question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873175/magento-banners-bewteen-products

Comment: you can use <?php if($i == 4){ ?> this only works one time.I guess u define your $i before foreach and in will iterate in side the foreach by $i++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
<?php if($i == 4){ ?>
   <li class="advert-banner-first">
      <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('catalogfirstbannermarkthalle')->toHtml(); ?>
   </li>
<?php } ?>
```

this only works one time.I guess u define your `$i` before foreach and in will iterate in side the foreach by `$i++`